# Is an incremented variable able to be used again in a function call in Python

Tags: python, function, class, variables

So, I was working on a game which requires a user's input for a move. I used a variable to count the number of turns within a function. The issue I have is that I want to recall the function as long as certain criteria is not met (x != y), so the user can enter another input. The problem is since I have used the variable in the function (turn), when I recall the function it will reset back to 1 and hence be stuck in an infinite loop.

Is there a way to use the variable (turn) and keep its total in this case for every additional turn?

Much appreciated, thanks!

PS. I'm new to Python

```html
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = 'A'
        
    def move(self, move):
        self.move = move
        turn = 1
        while x != y:
          if self.move == 's':
            print('correct')
            turn +=1
        change = input('Input a move: ')
        Player().move(change)
            
change = input('Input a move: ')
Player().move(change)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what object data members are for. Convert `turn` to a data member like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = 'A'
        self.turn = 1      # initialize in constructor instead of in 'move'

    def move(self, move):
        self.move = move
        while x != y:
          if self.move == 's':
            print('correct')
            self.turn +=1  # Access as a data member
        change = input('Input a move: ')
        Player().move(change)
```

Now, `self.turn` will be preserved between calls to `move`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `turn` to be a field in the Player class and set it to 1 in **init**. This way it will not get reset to 1 when calling `move()` multiple times on a Player object.